# In Community Portal we are getting Blue Outline for Header and Footer. Could you please help me out here for removing that Outline

Tags: community, experience-builder-page

We observe when we focus/focus-within on any input on the screen, we get this blue outline below adding Screenshot. We are using LWR framework for our community portal, also we are using custom header and footer component

In this we have override the style css, which is outline to none. but still it does not work for the Guest user?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you aware the the class community_byo-scoped-header-and-footer__main? You can add to header as below.

.community_byo-scoped-header-and-footer__main {
       flex: 1 0 auto;
       outline:none !important;
    }

This should overwrite the outline by data-f6-region.

Settings -> Advanced -> Edit Head Markup